# Redirect request to the right view

Tags: django

**Django==2.2.2**

**Urlpatterns:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^campaigns/$', CampaignsListView.as_view(), name="campaigns_list"),
    re_path(r'^campaigns/(?P<ids>\w+)/$', CampaignsDetailView.as_view(), name="campaigns_detail"),
]
```

**My url:**

```
http://localhost:8000/campaigns/?ids=44174865,44151214,44049374
```

**The problem:**
This url leads to CampaignsListView rather than to CampaignsDetailView. How can I direct this request to CampaignsDetailView?

Comment: That is logical, since the `ids` are *not* part of the path, this is the *querystring* part.

Comment: However given that I understand it correctly, this would still be a listview, since you will show all the elements that match with one of these ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?ids=44174865,44151214,44049374` part is *not* part of the *path* of a URL, but of the [*querystring* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring). You can not direct to a different view based on the querystring. The content of the querystring is processed into [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), a dictionary-like object.

You thus should handle this in the view itself. For example you can filter the list view given there are `ids` values:

```
class CampaignsListView(ListView):

    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        ids = request.GET.get('ids')
        if ids:
            try:
                return qs.filter(id__in=map(int, ids.split(',')))
            except ValueError:
                return qs
        return qs
```

Or you can check if the URL contains a queryset, and then let the `CampaignsDetailView` do the work, like:

```
class CampaignsListView(ListView):

    # ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'ids' in request.GET:
            return CampaignsDetailView.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Although it looks a bit "*ugly*".